# Sets are sorted from 0-9 every single time in python?! Not unordered

Tags: python, sorting, int, set

I thought it was a coincidence at first so I wrote up a test to try it out and it's true, I ran it 1 million times and every single time the set came back ordered and sorted. This only occurs when you use integers from 0-9 as soon as an integer > 9 is inserted then any integers inserted after will not be sorted. Why is this? Also for floats it kind of sorts it but isn't right all the time, so weird I thought they were completely unordered. Any advice on why 0-9 is sorted every time would be greatly appreciated, I didn't believe it at first either so here's the code I used you can easily run it yourself and see it's true.

```
import random

def check_set():
    constructing = True
    s = set()
    while constructing:
        x = random.randint(0, 9)
        if x not in s: s.add(x)
        if len(s) == 10: constructing = False
    return s
def main():
    for x in range(10000):
        l = list(check_set())
        if l != [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]:
            print('wow')
if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: Sets are not guaranteed to be ordered in Python. If it happens to be ordered under certain conditions it's simply due to the specifics of how sets are implemented in CPython. It is not a behavior you should count on.

Comment: Can you demonstrate that doing this with >9 will lead to non-sortedness? I think this will be sorted for **any** range 0-n.

Comment: @HeapOverflow try running these lines print({10,9,8,7,6,5,4,3,2,1})
print({9,11,10,8,75,7,6,73,5,4,3,72,2,1}) as you can see (my mistake it's 0-10 I think actually but either way still same point) 0-9 or 10 whatever will ALWAYS be in exact numerical order, but anything past 10 just gets put into semi random order

Comment: @mizuprogrammer Ah, you mean with gaps in the range, unlike what you're doing in the question (with *all* numbers from 0 to 9). Yes, then it's not always sorted. Simpler examples are `{8, 0}` or `{1, 8}`. If you put *all* 76 numbers from 0 to 75 into a set, I think it'll be sorted again.

Comment: @HeapOverflow This is exactly it! You're right, thank you! I wonder if there's a reason for that, just seems weird idk

Comment: "Unordered" doesn't mean they promise to shuffle things for you. It means they make no promises whatsoever about the order.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Those ints hash to themselves:

```
>>> [*map(hash, range(10))]
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
```

When you add the numbers 0 to 9 to a set, the set makes room for at least 10 numbers (actually 32, I think). So its internal array has at least the indexes 0 to 9. And because those numbers hash to themselves, they're stored in the set's internal array at their own index (value `i` gets stored at index `hash(i)`=`i`). So when you iterate it, you get them sorted.

Further illustration with smaller examples:

Sets start with internal size 8, and value `i` wants to go to index `hash(i) % 8`. So if you add `0` and `8`, both want to go to index `0`. The one that comes first actually gets to index `0`, the other has to go to some other (larger) index. Hence:

```
>>> {0, 8}, {8, 0}
({0, 8}, {8, 0})
```

If you instead add `1` and `8`, then `1` wants to go to index `1` and `8` wants to go to index `0`, so `8` always comes first regardless of insertion order:

```
>>> {1, 8}, {8, 1}
({8, 1}, {8, 1})
```

An example with 0 to 9:

```
>>> s = set()
>>> for i in 8, 9, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7:
        s.add(i)
        print(s)

{8}    # the only element (stored at index 0)
{8, 9}    # 9 gets stored at index 1, so after 8
{8, 9, 0}    # indices 0 and 1 are already taken, so 0 goes to some higher index
{8, 9, 0, 1}    # similar
{0, 1, 2, 8, 9}    # the set internally resized and re-added all values, each
                   # value ends up at its own index (e.g., 8 goes to index 8)
{0, 1, 2, 3, 8, 9}    # 3 goes to index 3
{0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 8, 9}    # same for the rest, all go to their own index...
{0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 8, 9}
{0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 8, 9}
{0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9}
```